# How to make poster behave like a hyperlink in html video

Tags: html, html5-video

I have this `audio` `mp3` which I wanna play in browser. The mp3 has an accompanying image and a url to navigate to when I click. So I put the mp3 in a `video` tag and made the image a poster like this

```js
//cache the poster
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "http://lorempixel.com/300/200";
// to make sure the poster is loaded before the video player appears
img.addEventListener("load", function(){
 var video = document.getElementById("demo-player");
  video.style.display = 'block';
 console.log("loaded!");
});
delete img;
```

```html
<video id="demo-player" controls="controls" style="display: none;"
    src="http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2003.mp3"
    poster="http://lorempixel.com/300/200">
</video>
```

Now I want to make the poster clickable which I intend to do by creating a click event listener on the video tag. My questions are

1. Is it correct to override the video's click event to make poster clickable? ( Are there any alternate methods?)
2. Is there a way I can bring in `cursor: pointer` to the poster?

P.S: I am using the video tag here because, my audio will be an ad/announcement with an image and a link to navigate(if interested). And after this 4-5 second pre-roll audio, there will be a lengthy content video.

Answer (score 1):

Apply css [`cursor: pointer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) property for the video tag. For handling click event attach a click event handler. I don't think anything is wrong with using click event handler  on [video tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) which doesn't effect the video controllers.

```js
//cache the poster
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "http://lorempixel.com/300/200";
// to make sure the poster is loaded before the video player appears
img.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var video = document.getElementById("demo-player");
  video.style.display = 'block';
  console.log("loaded!");
  video.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
  });
});
delete img;
```

```css
video {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<video id="demo-player" controls="controls" style="display: none;" src="http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2003.mp3" poster="http://lorempixel.com/300/200">
</video>
```